# C# adding custom header to HttpClient post requests

Tags: c#, winforms, post, header, httpclient

I am trying to make a `HttpClient` POST request, and everything went well until the server requested that the header is

```
"Content-Type":"application/json"
```

but every request returns with an error.

After further investigation, the header is not being added.

I am adding the header using :

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", @"application/json");
```

Is there any way to add the header or am I adding it the wrong way?

Comment: Add the Header to the `Content` of a HttpRequestMessage (`new StringContent(...)`). The request object if initialized with `HttpMethod.Post`

Comment: I am using 'httpclint.postasync()' method to send my request , the strange thing is that am using the same method to sign in to the server and works like charm I can read and retrieve info , the problem  occurred when I trying to get some extended info from the server

Answer (score 1):

there was no problem with the headers it self
I found a bug in the code was adding the headers multiple times on every request

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).